# When does an NSArray no longer contain the same item?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray storing NSDictionaries.  Each dictionary has two keys; a name and a sub-array containing 'items'.

I want to check if one of these dictionaries still remains in the NSArray after a certain operation.  Before the operation, I store a pointer called 'orginalDictionary' to the dictionary I am interested in.  I then perform my operation (which removes one of the 'items' from the sub-array inside that dictionary).  After the operation, I thought I could check if the Dictionary itself (not the removed item) still exists, using

```
if ([arrayOfDictionaries containsObject:originalDictionary]) {...
```

but it's not working as anticipated.  Even though the Array still contains the original dictionary (albeit with a modified sub-array inside it), the call returns that the array no longer contains that dictionary.

Can that be right? If an item in an array changes, does containsObject no longer recognize it as the same object?  Or is something else going on here?

**EDIT**
I'm starting to think that the way in which my array is populated is the root cause.  The array of dictionaries is created from one or more other arrays, depending on some settings.  **These** arrays are themselves populated using a fetch request, which created the dictionaries based on the fetched objects.  So, when there is a change to some data (or perhaps even if the fetch is fired simply by requesting the return result of the array), this is going to be rebuild the returned array, and the dictionaries inside will be new items.  Does this sound about right?  If so, I suppose I have no option but to store a self-managed unique key?

Comment: PS - I guess I can add a third value to each dictionary representing a unique key that I can compare instead? But I'd like to know if this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Sounds like what you are doing should work in theory. Are the dictionaries mutable dictionaries?  Also how are you changing the array within the dictionary that isn't removed? If they're not mutable dictionaries then any 'change' is actually giving you a new dictionary.

Comment: Also just read doco on the 'containsObject' method - note that it uses the 'isEqual' implementation to do the check (i.e. not just a straight pointer comparison) - could be possible that the NSDictionary isEqual isn't just a straight pointer comparison which could explain it.

Comment: @gamozzii - yes, they are NSMutableDictionaries.  The op-level array itself is populated from some other arrays, which in turn use a fetch request.  When I perform my operation, it will update an 'item'.  This will result in a different set of fetched objects, which will in turn mean different items in one dictionary's sub-array, and it is possible that the dictionary itself is no longer present following the change. This is what I am trying to test for.

Comment: @gamozzii - You got me thinking (see edit to question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`containsObject:` determines whether an object representing the same *value* is in the array, this is the same test that `isEqual:` and `indexOfObject:` use. E.g. two completely different dictionaries which contain the same key/value pairs will compare equal as they both represent the same value - just as two integer variables compare equal if they contain the same integer value.

The method `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` looks for whether the *object* is present in the array.

However that doesn't directly solve your problem. If you actually have an `NSMutableArray` which contains `NSMutableDictionary`s and you keep a reference to the `NSMutableDictionary` you're checking for then value or object comparison should work...

Either use the debugger to track the actual references (addresses/pointers), or dump them to the console using `NSLog()` and the `%p` format (e.g. `NSLog(@"Tracked dict: %p", originalDictionary)`).

Comment: Thank you for the direction.  I've started logging the address of the pointer, and it doesn't change from when it is created to just prior to the comparison.  If I loop through my dictionaries logging each one's address, the matching dictionary indeed returns a DIFFERENT address from the *originalDictionary, - but this is to be expected right?  The pointer and the dictionary itself will each have a unique address?  Or should I be expecting them to be consistent?

Comment: I edited the question with some more detail about how the arrays are populated.

Comment: @BenPackard: Pointers *are* addresses. Assuming you declared `originalDictionary` as `NSMutableDictionary *originalDictionary`, its value is the address of the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  It seems I am repopulating the array when ever I ask for it, which means the dictionary is a different object.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer since it is the most complete description of the containsObject method.  It helped me rule it out as the cause of my issues, and continue looking elsewhere in my code.